# Nil ring version of Burnside's problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

The famous Burnside group of exponent $n$  over a set $G$ of generators  is the
group defined by generators $g\in G$ and relations $h^n=1$ where $h$ is any
product of elements of $G$.

Likewise, let $G$ be any set of indeterminates, let ${\mathbb Q}[G]$
denote the ring of noncommutative polynomials in $G$, and let ${\mathbb Q}'[G]$
denote the hyperplane in  ${\mathbb Q}[G]$ of polynomials with no constant term.
Denote by $I_n$ the ideal generated by all $n$-th powers of elements of
${\mathbb Q}'[G]$. Then $B_n(G)={\mathbb Q}'[G]/I$ might be called the "Burnside
ring" of exponent $n$ over $G$.

When $n=2$, $B_2(G)$ is simply the exterior algebra over $G$.

Is it true that $B_n(G)$ is always finite dimensional when $G$ is finite ? Is  a (more or less) simply described basis known ?